# How to insert 3d line into postgis database?

Tags: postgis, qgis

I have 3D line which I exported from GRASS in .shp format. When I try to insert this line to Postgis database with QuantumGIS, it gives an error:

> ERROR:  Invalid type name - valid ones are:
>       POINT, MULTIPOINT,
>       LINESTRING, MULTILINESTRING,
>       POLYGON, MULTIPOLYGON,
>       CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, MULTICURVE,
>       CURVEPOLYGON, MULTISURFACE,
>       GEOMETRY, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,
>       POINTM, MULTIPOINTM,
>       LINESTRINGM, MULTILINESTRINGM,
>       POLYGONM, MULTIPOLYGONM,
>       CIRCULARSTRINGM, COMPOUNDCURVEM, MULTICURVEM
>       CURVEPOLYGONM, MULTISURFACEM,
>       or GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONM
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('', $1 , $2 , $3 , $4 , $5 , $6 )"
>   PL/pgSQL function "addgeometrycolumn" line 4 at SQL statement

Can someone help me? How can I insert this 3d line into postgis database?

Comment: What version of postgis are you using?

Comment: Postgis 1.5 for PostgreSQL 8.4

Comment: Try http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5SVN/ST_Force_3D.html - Note: PostGIS 2.0 adds extensive support for 3D

Comment: There's already a QGIS ticket: http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/747

Answer (score 2):

SPIT can't do this (due to [bug #747](https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/747) mentioned above), so you will need a different method.

Here are a few tools that you can try (and as far as I know, they all work with 3D geometries):

- **[shp2pgsql](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage)**: command-line program, installed with PostGIS
- **shp2pgsql-gui** / **PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader**: installed with PostGIS, look for it in either pgAdmin III plugins (puzzle icon) or (on MS Windows) Start > Programs > PostGIS for PostgreSQL
- **PostGIS Manager**: Python plugin for Quantum GIS, GUI built for `shp2pgsql`
- **[ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)**: command-line program, installed with GDAL/OGR, good for converting other types of files (other than just Shapefiles)

Comment: If shp2pgsql can import 3D shapefiles, you can also try QGIS plugin "PostGIS Manager". It offers a GUI for shp2pgsql.